# Custom Exception with Entity Framework and Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, error-handling

I am following this Asp .Net tutorial as a guide:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-control-part-2-adding-a-business-logic-layer-and-unit-tests

I have created a custom error to prevent duplicate records on insert and update

```
Public Class DuplicateAgencyException
Inherits Exception

Public Sub New(ByVal message As String)
    MyBase.New(message)
End Sub
End Class
```

I have created a validation method that checks for duplication on insert or update:

```
Public Sub ValidateAgencyName(ByVal agency As agency_temp)
        If Not IsNothing(agency) Then
            Dim duplicateAgency As agency_temp = AgencyRepository.GetAgencyByName(agency.agency_name).FirstOrDefault()
            If Not IsNothing(duplicateAgency) AndAlso duplicateAgency.agency_id <> agency.agency_id Then
                Throw New DuplicateAgencyException(String.Format("Agency: {0} already exists.", duplicateAgency.agency_name))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I run a unit test to insert a record, and purposefully insert a duplicate, and it throws the correct error. Now I need to handle this error with the ObjectDataSource that displays this data, such as OnInserted and OnUpdated, but I can't even get to that point. When I insert a record, I get the error assistant telling me that DuplicateAgencyException was unhandled by user code. Do I need a try...Catch there? (I did try that to no avail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to wrap your exception within the methods referenced by the events you mention in a try catch block as you suggest. You should wrap the existing code like so

```
MethodName(params)
《
try 《 /// existing code 

》
catch (ExceptionType ex) 《
/// error handling code
》

》
```

If you post your event handling code and the aspx i can be more specific. Please excuse any errots wrote this on my phone.

Comment: I thought in ASP .Net I should not using try/catch. I should be letting exceptions trickle up to Global.asax to be handled there for the whole app. Also, it seems to have little to do with the code I posted above. Any error is stopping the app and opening the error assistant in visual studio, which makes me think this is some  kinbd of configuration problem. my error configuration is pretty basic: